# Get html content with RegEx between several tags

Tags: regex, actionscript

For example there are some html tags `<div id="test"><div><div>testtest</div></div></div></div></div></div>`

From that html, I need to get this  `<div id="test"><div><div>testtest</div></div></div>`

Current regex `/<div id=\"test\">.*(</div>){3}/gim`

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Use an HTML parser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 is why. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Looks like a good use for a regex. You just have to get as many corresponding closes as opens, eh? A greedy match isn't really going to be what you want here.

Comment: I'm using ActionScript. I need exact 3 div closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the specific requirement of needing exactly three closing  tags, this regular expression should do the trick:

```
(<div.*?>)+.*?(</div>){3}
```

The trick here is to use the lazy star (*?) to keep the catch-all (.) character from matching more than you'd like.